# Compounding interest with additions formulas

Tags: algorithms, logarithms, exponential-function, finance

Given

`principal` initial amount
`time` number of years
`rate` interest rate as decimal
`n` number of periods per `time` to compound `principal` by `rate`
`a` amount to add to principal at either beginning or end of each `n` period

where

`principal` is equal to `1`
`time` is equal to `1`
`rate` is equal to `0.03`, or `3%`
`n` is equal to `12`, or monthly
`a` is equal to `10`

The result that derived here is `124.68033078653431`, which is equivalent to initial `principal` `121` compounded monthly, not initial `principal` `1` with addition `a` `10` made each `n` month then compounded.

What are the applicable mathematical formulas to determine the current value of the accrued interest and principal where the addition `a` is made a) at the beginning of each period, or b) at the end of each period?

When is the interest applied to the principal during the given period?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interest is computed at the end of each period.  You can just consider each addition to be a new principal.  The first $1$ becomes $1(1+r)^n$ at the end of $n$ periods.  If you add $10$ at the end of the first period is becomes $10(1+r)^{n-1}$ because there is one less period to draw interest.  If you add $10$ at the end of each period, you get a geometric series to sum: $10[(1+r)^{n-1}+(1+r)^{n-2}+\ldots (1+r)^1+1]=10\frac {(1+r)^n-1}{1+r}$

Comment: What is the precise result? The online calculators which tried when attempting to verify the result that derived here provided different final amounts, which, in part led to the current question http://www.thecalculatorsite.com/finance/calculators/compoundinterestcalculator.php : 123.00; https://www.depositaccounts.com/tools/compound-interest-calculator.aspx : 122.67. Also http://www.moneychimp.com/calculator/compound_interest_calculator.htm allows the addition to be made at either beginning or end of the period, which also provides different results for each option.

Comment: I am not going to debug online calculators.  The above gives you a value to compare with.  Alternately you can make your own spreadsheet.

Comment: Was able to get result `123.68577853630043`  by adding `a` to initial principal at each iteration  less than `n` periods per `time` `principal = principal + a` and multiplying `principal`  by  `e^(rate * (rate * --n))`, where `n` is decremented at each iteration less than inital `n`; and result `123.64550923392724` by multiplying `principal` by `1+rate^(rate*--n)`

Comment: I just made a spreadsheet.  With a deposit of $1$ at the start of the first month and a deposit of $10$ at the end of months $1$ through $12$ I get $122.6942436$ at the end of month $12$.  I think your $123$ is clearly too high because you have $56$ on deposit on average, so the simple interest would be $1.68$.  A little compounding gets to my number.

Comment: Discussed the case with a financial professional. The average daily balance was cited as the primary variable considered by an institution. They also noted that the result does depend on whether the addition is made at the beginning or at the end of the period. Significantly, the result depends on the respective established methods of the particular institution. Ironically, the suggestion was to use the online calculators as a barometer of the average expected result; interpreted here as meaning "results may vary"; which is reflected in the results of  the various online calculators tried.

Comment: Can you include the spreadsheet at your Answer, or post a link to the same? BTW, was not able to compose the formula `10((1+r)^n-1/1+r)` using code to return the equivalent of the long form series at the adjacent left of the formula.

Comment: I just made a column of the deposits which were assumed at the end of the month.  The first $1$ I made end of month $0$.  The end of month balance is then the previous end of month balance times $1.0025$ plus the new deposit.

Comment: The different results returned by online calculators, in part, spawned the inquiry, as did not get same result using the math that was trying; they appear to be using formulas similar to https://jsfiddle.net/syd2oem2/2/. The other portion of the question is what is the precise mathematical result, which your described spreadsheet would appear to reflect. Can you provide a means to compare your results with the various results posted thus far into the inquiry?

Comment: The spreadsheet approach is much more flexible because it is easy to change the deposit every month, or to reflect contributions part way through the month if that is accepted.  I gave the precise formula above for recurring deposits of the same amount for $n$ months.

Comment: What is the flaw with the approaches at linked jsfiddle? Is the result provided at second linked calculator `122.67` closest to being accurate? Is `123` the rounded result of `122.6`? This board appears well equipped to render a spreadsheet at Answer, can you include your month by month results at your Answer; that is, the spreadsheet that you created that are referencing? Where does the `Math.pow()` approach at linked jsfiddle err in the calculation?

Comment: When adding `a` to `principal` after compounding interest am getting `123.04277916708712` https://jsfiddle.net/syd2oem2/4/. What needs to be adjusted in the calculations to get `122.6942436122.6942436`?

Comment: From which variables is `1.0025` derived?

Comment: It is $3\%$ annual interest divided by $12$ to get interest per month plus 1

Comment: Ok. Still not following the procedure at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2528122/compounding-interest-with-additions-formulas/2529315?noredirect=1#comment5223931_2529315. You describe making initial deposit at the end of the month, then adding previous balance multiplied by `rate/n` - though you add the new deposit which would not occur until the end of that month, yes? Why would not the initial principal `1` be accruing interest during the first period, albeit at `0.0025`?

Comment: Yes, it is.  I put the initial deposit in at the end of month 0 so I was consistently doing end of month deposits.  Then yes, the 1 earns interest in month 1.  New deposits do not earn interest because they come in at the end of the month, so the first 10 earns interest in month 2 and on.

Comment: Got it https://jsfiddle.net/syd2oem2/5/